# Invalid package.json: SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 175 Make sure the file is encoded as utf-8

Tags: javascript, node.js, nw.js

Создаю своё первое приложение на nw.js.Есть 3 файла. Все файлы в кодировке UTF-8. Первых два файла это index.html и style.css(думаю понятно зачем они). Последний файл это package.json.Ниже содержимое. Приложение запускается корректно. Но при попытке скомпилировать, командой `nwbuild ./ -p win64`, выдаёт ошибку:

```
Invalid package.json: SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 175
Make sure the file is encoded as utf-8.
```

Система Ubuntu Gnome 3.
Помогите пожайлуста исправить это, буду рад любой помощи.

Вот содержимое package.json(Взял с примера):

```
{
"main": "index.html",
"name": "dummydemo",
"description": "Dummy demo of nnwjs app",
"version": "0.0.1",
"keywords": [ "demo", "nwjs" ],
"window": {
"title": "Dummy demo",
//"icon": "icon.png",
"toolbar": false,
"frame": true,
"width": 700,
"height": 400,
"position": "mouse",
"min_width": 400,
"min_height": 200,
"max_width": 800,
"max_height": 600
},
"author": "nedudi",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"moment": "latest",
"handlebars": "^2.0.0"
}
}
```

Comment: В JSON не бывает комментариев

Comment: Спасибо, не знал. Но почему тогда приложение запускается?

Comment: Без понятия. Скорее все приложение никак не использует package.json